# Count raster value in a bounding box (spatial extent)

Tags: python, raster, r

Given a bounding box, how can I count the number of specific values (say, I am interested in the number of `value == 1` ) in a raster in 1) arcpy, or 2) raster package in R?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `R`, use `crop` to extract the values and (*e.g.*) `table` to count them.

---

As an example, let's create a 1 degree grid covering the globe:

```
library(raster)
x.raster <- raster(outer(179:0, 0:359, `+`), xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90)
```

The bounding box is converted to an `extent` object in order to use `crop`:

```
y.extent <- extent(cbind(c(-125,20), c(-60,50)))
y.raster <- crop(x.raster, y.extent)
```

Having done that, tabulation is straightforward:

```
table(getValues(y.raster))
```

In this output the first row lists the values and the second lists their corresponding counts:

```
165 166 167 ... 257 258
  1   2   3 ...   2   1
```

As a check we can plot the raster and the extent:

```
plot(x.raster)
plot(y.extent, add=T)
```

[image: Map]

Answer (score 3):

A minor addition: you could also use (memory-safe) function "freq":

Following the answer by whuber:

```
library(raster)
x.raster <- raster(outer(179:0, 0:359, '+'), xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90)
y.extent <- extent(cbind(c(-125,20), c(-60,50)))
y.raster <- crop(x.raster, y.extent)
```

But now do:

```
freq(y.raster)
```

It only matters for very large objects (raster on file). 'freq' returns a two-column matrix (value/count) whereas 'table' returns a table.

Comment: is there anyway just perform spatial query rather than cropping the image? Cropping might be very slow for processing.

Comment: Cropping ought to be very fast. As a test, I timed the `crop` operation for a one minute grid covering the earth: it has 10800 rows and 21600 columns (233,280,000 cells). The crop was executed in 1.36 seconds total elapsed time.

Comment: I also think it should be fast, but you could compare the above with this spatial query: `v <- extract(x.raster, y.extent)`   followed by  `table(v)`

Comment: Robert, what library is `extract` from? It's not part of `raster` and the `R` help system (`??`) does not find any function with this name, either.

Comment: It is a function in the raster package. ?extract shows that (at least for me it does)